Unable to reduce MacOS partition below 50GB
I have a Mac that I want to install windows on using Bootcamp partition. It is a MacBook Pro 13-inch 2017 running Monterey 12.7.4. When using Bootcamp partition, it won't let me reduce the MacOS partition size below 50GB, forcing me to keep "10GB free". I just did a format and clean install of the OS, so I have no files, downloads, apps, etc whatsoever beyond the Windows .iso file. The disk should be 121GB total. How do I remove everything possible from MacOS in order to increase the size of my Windows partition? To be clear, I don't care about MacOS and don't intend to use it -- I would reduce the MacOS partition to 0 if I could.
In case it's useful, here is the output of diskutil list
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         121.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Mac HD - Data⁩           9.6 GB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 270.4 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Mac HD⁩                  15.4 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk1s5s1 ```


If you do not care about macOS, then why not just install Windows? All Intel processors used in MacBook Pro 13-inch 2017 models are list as Windows 10 22H2 supported. None of these are listed as Windows 11 supported. However, this does not necessarily mean Windows 11 cannot be installed on your Mac. I have installed Windows 11 on 2007, 2011 and 2013 iMacs.

I'd very much like to! I don't have an external keyboard or mouse though, and I've been told you need those in order to wipe MacOS and install windows only, since deleting MacOS will delete the keyboard and mouse drivers.

According to your diskutil output the Mac HD is 15.4GB and Mac HD - Data only 9.6. I do not see any part of the drive that shows "free space."
I would bet that macOS wants/needs a certain amount of space. In your case that is 15.4GB for the OS and 9.6GB for the data. MacOS will usually show this in Finder as one contiguous "drive" even though you can't change anything on the OS portion.
The rest are things macOS needs to boot and are quite small comparatively speaking.
I doubt that any of the displayed APFS volumes can be made smaller, but perhaps people wiser than me know better.
You have a little over 42GB used space (give or take a half a GB or so). Room enough for a Windows/BootCamp installation or perhaps even Linux.

Even at 15.4GB and 9.6GB for the Data, that's only 25GB. Bootcamp won't let me reduce the MacOS partition below 50GB. I do not have any files on my computer beyond what comes pre-installed with a clean format, so I don't have anything else taking up space.
